# Determine if field (on submit event) is a dropdown or a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, backbone.js, model-view-controller

My issue is that on my button that is named submit; I want to save data to my model from the view once the submit button is clicked. I want to store each field input into an object so I can store the data in my model. The issue is that I want to determine if its a drop down or a input because that is how I am retrieving the value. But if there is a better way I am all ears. Maybe I don't need to know the difference it whether its a text input or a dropdown.

Here is the code I am messing with:

```
submit: function(e) {
    var field = $(e.currentTarget);

},

selectionChanged: function(e) {
    var field = $(e.currentTarget);
    var value = $("option:selected", field).val();
    var data = {};
    data[field.attr('similarID')] = value;
    this.model.set(data);
},

fieldChanged: function(e) {
    var field = $(e.currentTarget);
    var data = {};
    data[field.attr('similarID')] = field.val();
    this.model.set(data);
},

//update values in model from form
update: function(e) {
    var val = $(this.ui.ageAnnuitization).val();
    this.model.set({'ageAnnuitization': val});
}
```

As you can see I have a fieldChanged and a selectionChnaged; but I don't need both of those. I'd like to slim it down and make the submit do it all. Which is store the data into the model and set the data into the model.

My next question has to do with finding each field name. If I have:

FirstName
LastName
Age
State

What is an easy way to do what I am doing here:

```
data[field.attr('similarID')] = field.val();
```

Instead of using a similarID for all; how can I use a class name that is specific to each field wihtout making 4 lines of code doing the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `serializeArray` to collect all data on submit of the form. `serializeArray` will return you the array of name and value pair of of all the fields in forms, you can simply iterate over those array values and create the required object then set it to your model. and it works good with all kind of input types text, password, select etc.

**[serializeArray docs](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/#serializeArray)**

See the woking example below.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var serializedArray = $this.serializeArray() || [];

        var modelObject = {};
        serializedArray.forEach(function(obj){
            modelObject[obj.name] = obj.value;
        });
        
        console.log(modelObject);
        // Now you can use `modelObject` object to set the model.
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
    First Name:
    <input name="fname" />
    <br/>
    Last Name:
    <input name="lname" />
    <br/>
    Select Box:
    <select name="sbox">
        <option value="opt1">Options 1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Options 2</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/rrb61gmd/)**